# Automatically selecting feature when another feature in different layer shares attribute data?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-9.3, data-driven-pages, map-book

I have a mapset displaying foraging areas, each with a unique ID. I spatially joined the mapbooks layer, so each mapbook sheet identifies the foraging area it is depicting (1:1), so sheet 5 is foraging area 18. So when sheet 5 draws, I want it to select foraging area 18, which has a matching attribute.  I want to do this so I can change the symbology of the target feature to make the map stand out more.

I'm using ArcGIS 9.3.x with the mapbooks extension.

Comment: For version 9.3 within the data frame properties is there a Data Frame and Extent Indicator tab (Could not remember I'm using a newer version)?

Comment: That only will select the viewable window. I'm trying to select the feature with the matching attribute of the sheet.

Comment: Can you make the indicator layer the foraging area layer?

Comment: hm. possibly, I've never tried using the mapsheet index with irregular shapes.

Comment: I not sure if I understand fully what you are trying to accomplish, but could you just create a definition query within the mapbooks interface on the foraging layer to only show the one of interest?  Then have a 2nd layer of the the foraging below that showing all polygons?

Comment: Yes, that would be a good work around.  I, however, am not sure how do do that. Can you give me any guidance?

Comment: It is a shame that you are restricted to 9.3 because I think the [**Page Definition Queries**](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.2/index.html#//00s90000003p000000) of **Data Driven Pages** would make this easy.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not 100% sure if this will work in v9.3, but it does work in v10.

1. Set your foraging areas as the indicator layer (use a unique ID column for Page Number)
2. Create another data frame in the layout view (data frame 2), and put it on-top of your original data frame and make the background white and include all the layers (basemap and indicator).
3. For data frame 2, go to Data Frame properties>Extent Indicators tab, and set the original data frame as the show extent
4. For data frame 2, go to Data Frame properties>Data Frame tab, and set the Extent option to Other Data Frame and change the margin % to 100.

When you toggle through the books the active foraging feature should change and be highlighted (outlined) in the map.